# Creating Shipping Promotions with specific item in netsuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

Free shipping promotion on specific item but it's  applying free shipping promotion to all items in Sales order

Answer (score 0):

Line level discount items have an option to only apply to the item above if not mistaken. You can use that to apply the promotion to the specific item.

Comment: I need the free shipping charge on certain items but it's not a discount on the item.